# Quotients to 2 Decimal places

Tags: c#

So I need to get a quotient to 2 decimal places like 0.33, but do I need to use doubles all the way down or can I use integers for everything except the quotient and then just use double or decimal for the quotient? It is also breaking because of the quotient. If anyone could help me I would be extremely grateful :)

```
int firstnumber;
        int secondnumber;
        decimal quotient;

        firstnumber = int.Parse(inputTextBox1.Text);
        secondnumber = int.Parse(inputTextBox2.Text);

        sumLabel.Text = (firstnumber + secondnumber).ToString();

        differenceLabel.Text = (firstnumber - secondnumber).ToString();

        productLabel.Text = (firstnumber * secondnumber).ToString();

        quotient = decimal.Parse(quotientLabel.Text);
        quotient = (firstnumber / secondnumber).tostring;
```

Comment: Dividing an int by an int will *always* result in an int.

Comment: You have to use doubles/decimal for decimal. It has more precision than integer.

Comment: possible dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10851273/why-integer-division-in-c-sharp-returns-an-integer-but-not-a-float

Comment: so inputtextbox1 and inputtextbox2 must be decimals?

Comment: firstNumber OR secondNumber must be decimals

Comment: No, that's not true, you just need a cast. See Reed Copsey's answer.

Comment: You: _can I use integers for everything except the quotient and then just use double or decimal for the quotient_ Sure! Just cast one of the integers to `double` (or `decimal`). The other integer will be "promoted" to `double` automatically. The division will then be a floating-point division.

Answer (score 6):

You can cast the integers to `decimal` or `double` when assigning your variable, then assign the label from the results:

```
quotient = ((decimal)firstnumber / secondnumber);
quotientLabel.Text = quotient.ToString("N2");
```

Comment: Note that `"N2"` will insert thousands separators, as in `"7,654,321.09"` (English culture here). Use `"F2"` if that is not wanted.