# Does Int32 return decimals?

Tags: c#, rounding

Trying to define an Int32 variable here, but need it to return whole number, not decimals.

So I have this:

```
Int32 HalfCount = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round(11 / 2, 0));
```

But get error.

Than I use this:

```
Int32 HalfCount = Math.Round(11/2);
```

Get another error.  Can not convert Double to Decimal or something like that.

How am I supposed to declare an Int32 to be rounded in half?  Or does Int32 automatically round it?

Could I just do this?

```
Int32 HalfCount = (11/2);
```

Doesn't look like a syntax error, but I have to know before I run the code, cause it will jack everything up if it is wrong.

I just need to return a whole number (without decimals), I don't care which way it goes (up or down is fine by me).

Comment: What do you mean by "I have to know before I run the code, cause it will jack everything up if it is wrong."

Comment: Can't you just try these things out in a small console application, and see?

Comment: Write a test method first instead of writing code and running it directly on productionand hoping it works.

Comment: "But get error" is *never* enough description of what is wrong. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-list

Comment: How to write a test method without writing code?

Comment: @BoltClock - It will completely ruin the site.  Does that make any sense now?

Comment: How about writing a small separate test program? Then any site won´t be affected.

Comment: Simple question... and all I get are downvotes.  Thanks guys!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why integer division in c# returns an integer but not a float?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10851273/why-integer-division-in-c-sharp-returns-an-integer-but-not-a-float)

Comment: @lucounu - I don't mock a test environment.  I simply don't have enough knowledge on how to set one up.

Comment: @Solomon Closson: File > New Project, Console Application. You can easily test a simple integer division in a console application without jacking anything up (except that console application).

Comment: Jon, your link is a dead one, or is it a self-referential wheeze?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last example will work, especially since you don't care which way the value is rounded.

```
Int32 HalfCount = (11/2);  // result is 5
```

This will drop the decimal portion of the result, storing only the integer portion in `HalfCount`.

Comment: Thank You VERY VERY MUCH!  And also Thanks for not being a smart ass about it!

Comment: @Solomon Closson , no one was a smart ass. You should flat-out not be in a position to "jack things up" in any production environment before you fix how you're working.

Comment: Yeah, I agree, but don't know how to set up a test environment either, other than on localhost, which is what I'm doing now.

Comment: Thanks, I need to start doing that!

Answer (score 0):

Int32 simply return unsigned integer which it does not return any decimal digits.

Comment: Int32 is signed. Also, this question is about more than just the data type, it's about division. :)

Comment: The result of the division is finally storing in integer variable.