# Rounding a number using C#

Tags: c#, math, rounding

I have created an accreditation system where a user can take exams. On marking the exam i wish to return a percentage figure. So i am taking the correct questions figure, dividing it by the number of questions in the exam and multiplying it by 100.

My issue is rounding the number up. So if the figure returned was 76.9 my code is giving me 76 where rounded up it should be 77 etc.

this is the line of code i that is working this out...

```
int userScorePercentageConvert = (int)decimal.Round((correctQuestionsForAttempt.Count / dvAttemptQuestions.Count * 100), MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
```

Can anyone tell me how to amend this piece of code so it is rounding correctly

i.e. 43.4 = 44 | 67.7 = 68 | 21.5 = 22

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Just a guess, try casting correctQuestionsForAttempt.Count to a (double) before doing the division.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you're using [integer division](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10851273/why-integer-division-in-c-sharp-returns-an-integer-but-not-a-float) right here:

```
(correctQuestionsForAttempt.Count / dvAttemptQuestions.Count * 100)
```

With integer division in a case like this, you'll always end up with 0 or 100.

This will work:

```
(100.0 * correctQuestionsForAttempt.Count / dvAttemptQuestions.Count)
```

Also, from what you describe, you want a [`Ceiling`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.ceiling%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) function (think of it as rounding up), not a `Round` (rounding to the nearest integer, with options on how to round midpoint values).

```
int userScorePercentageConvert = (int)Math.Ceiling(100.0 * correctQuestionsForAttempt.Count / dvAttemptQuestions.Count);
```

Answer (score 6):

I believe you are looking for [`Math.Ceiling`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1cz5da1c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
decimal number = 43.4M;
int roundedNumber = (int) Math.Ceiling(number);
```

That will give you `44`

Answer (score 4):

You can simply do `Math.Ceiling(43.4)`

Answer (score 0):

Just add .5 to your number before casting it

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a rounding issue; it's a number type issue.

The `.Count` property of a collection (I'm assuming that's what `correctQuestionsForAttempt` and `dvAttemptQuestions` are) is an `int`. Dividing an `int` by an `int` will give you another `int`, without any decimal places. Truncating the decimal likes this gives the appearance of rounding down. The result is that your call to `decimal.Round` is trying to round something that is already an integer.

If you multiple the number correct by 100 *before* you divide by the total, this issue should be corrected.

Answer (score 0):

You want Math.Ceiling() - see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zx4t0t48%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

In your context, it would be used as follows:

```
int userScorePercentageConvert = (int)Math.Ceiling((correctQuestionsForAttempt.Count / dvAttemptQuestions.Count * 100));
```