# how to get float value in c# in the result

Tags: c#

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int a, b;
             Console.Write("Enter two values :- ");
             a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
             b = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
             float c =(a / b);
            Console.WriteLine("\nAnswer is :- {0}",c);            
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the classic integer divison question. One of your operands has to be a float for the division to work as you expect.

Comment: Use `Convert.ToDouble(..)` for `a` and `b`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why integer division in c# returns an integer but not a float?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10851273/why-integer-division-in-c-sharp-returns-an-integer-but-not-a-float)

Answer (score 2):

The expression `(a / b)` (where both `a` and `b` are ints) will result in an `int`, which is then converted to a float when assigned to `c`.

To get a float, you should make either `a` or `b` a float, or *cast* one to a float:

```
float c = (a / (float)b); // Int divided by float is a float
```

Or, just make `a` and `b` floats in the first place:

```
float a, b;
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `a` and `b` are both integers, the result of division is also an integer. After the division, it is cast to a float, but it is too late by then.

For this to work, at least one of the operands must be a float. Try this:

```
float c = ((float) a) / b;
```