# How do I make my progress bar count up instead of down?

Tags: c#

I have an application that shows one item at a time from a list that they chose from. I want to create a progress bar to show their status of percentage complete.

To do this I think I need 3 numbers:

1.) the number I want to end up with (ie. 100%)

2.) the number of items the user selected

3.) Since the survey I created presents a new item from the list object the user filled with their selection everytime the user clicks the `btnNext` I need a number that will iterate everytime the hits `btnNext`

```
int RAC = Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["count"]) - 2; 
//starts at 0 and goes up to however many selections the user made minus1 or 'countSelection - 1'
```

With those three numbers here is what I tried

```
Response.Write(100 / RAC);
```

but this starts at 100 and goes down to 0. How can I reverse this?

Comment: swapping them will work i think ``RAC/100``

Comment: (total_completed/ total_questions) * 100 = % done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need 2 numbers:

1. The total number of items (not in percentage). I believe you stated
   this was: `countSelection`
2. The number of items the user has completed.
   This appears to be: `Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["count"]) - 2;`

Then you can calculate the percentage completed using the following:

```
int totalNumberOfItems = countSelection;
int itemsCompleted = Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["count"]) - 2;
int currentProgressPercent = itemsCompleted / totalNumberOfItems * 100;

string displayString = string.Format("{0}/{1} ({2}% complete)", 
    itemsCompleted, totalNumberOfItems, currentProgressPercent);
```

Comment: i took lunch right after I posted the question and ended up using 

`itemscompleted * 100 / totalNumberOfItems`

Answer (score 1):

To make a progress bar all you need are the total number of items and the number of selected items.  If you use a min of 0 and a max of 100, the "progress" would then just be:

```
(100 * selected) / total
```

Note that you multiple the selected times 100 first, otherwise you would be using integer division for `(selected / total)` which would be `0` unless `selected` was equal to `total`

Comment: Maybe worth noting, that [integer division is not floating point division](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10851273/why-integer-division-in-c-sharp-returns-an-integer-but-not-a-float).

Comment: @qqbenq That's why I multiply by 100 first.  You could cast to double but since the result needs to be an integer this works just as well.