# How do i get the total average?

Tags: c#

```
private void txtFinal_Leave_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int prelim;
        int midterm;
        int final;
        decimal average;
        string remarks;

        prelim = int.Parse(txtPrelim.Text);
        midterm = int.Parse(txtMidterm.Text);
        final = int.Parse(txtFinal.Text);

        average = (prelim + midterm + final) / 3;
        txtAverage.Text = average.ToString();

        if (average >= 75)
        {
            remarks = "passed";
        }
        else
        {
            remarks = "failed";
        }
        txtRemarks.Text = remarks;


       // this is the output 83 passed
       // I want to be like this 83.25 passed

    }
```

Comment: you can't get decimals with integers

Comment: try `/ 3M` instead of `/ 3`

Comment: Should be duplicate. Are you really sure no one hit this issue before? Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10851273/why-integer-division-in-c-sharp-returns-an-integer-but-not-a-float helps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
average = (prelim + midterm + final) / 3.0m;
```

This will fix your problem.

Int is an integer type; dividing two ints performs an integer division, i.e. the fractional part is truncated since it can't be stored in the result type (also int!). Decimal, by contrast, has got a fractional part. By invoking Decimal.Divide, your int arguments get implicitly converted to Decimals.

You can enforce non-integer division on int arguments by explicitly casting at least one of the arguments to a floating-point type, e.g.: 3.0m this is casting to **decimal** !

Answer (score -2):

please upgrade your code as follow:

```
average = Convert.ToDecimal(prelim + midterm + final) / 3;
txtAverage.Text = string.Format("{0:0.00}", average);
```