# Why does var evaluate to int instead of double?

Tags: c#, .net

In the following code, why does the compiler evaluates result variable as 3(integer) but not as 3.5(float or double)?

```
void Main()
{
    var result = 7/2;
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You are dividing an int by an int. That always results in an int. The var evaluation just follows that.

Comment: because both 7 and 2 are int so compiler will try to return the result as int.  just convert any one as double, you will get the result as double.

Comment: For the same reason that `7/2` is `3` http://ideone.com/QrtMep

Comment: Why this question reopened? o.O Isn't [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10851273/why-integer-division-in-c-sharp-returns-an-integer-but-not-a-float) a duplicate? Am I voted it wrong?

Comment: I would expect someone that has been answering c# questions since 2010 to be able to research this question very easily, especially since its one of the first things most will probably learn.

Comment: @Soner, I voted to re-open based on the fact it was using `var` which made it subtly different. _Very_ subtly because, now that I reflect more deeply, I think it _is_ actually a dupe, the `var` having little to do with the root problem. So, either as a reformed voter or hypocrite, I may have to vote to close :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo Thanks for response. Yeah, you are quite right because `var` doesn't do _anything_ about how `7 / 2` expression evaluated and returned type or value. It might be better to close it again `:)`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because, if you divide one `int` by another, the result is an `int`. That's specified [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3b1ff23f.aspx).

> When you divide two integers, the result is *always* an integer. For example, the result of `7 / 3` is `2`.

Then `var` just uses the expression type to create an `int` because that's what you've told it you want (albeit implicitly). If you want a `double`, you need to force the type of the expression to a double:

```
var result = 7.0 / 2;
```

or, if you're using `int` *variables* where you can't just tack on a `.0`:

```
int seven = 7;
int two = 2;
var result = (double)seven / two;
```

Answer (score 6):

Because you are doing **Integer division.**

You need to convert one of the value to **float/double** to get the expected result.

Try This:

```
void Main()
{
  var result = 7/2.0; //convert 7 or 2 to double
  Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Operators like `/` are also like functions. Signature for `int/int` is

```
public static int operator /(int numerator, int denominator)
{
    //
}
```

So the return value is `int`.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, you're getting 3 rather than 3.5 because you're performing integer division.  What most answers have implied but not stated explicitly is *why* it's integer division.  It's integer division because both operands are integers.  They are both integers because 7 and 2 are *integer literals*.  If you add a decimal point to either literal, it would become a *double literal*, resulting in double division being performed rather than integer division.  Double division is used when dividing a double by an int or an int by a double.