# Can this code look cleaner in C#?

Tags: c#, casting, coding-style

I have a C programming background and I am used to doing ugly things.

Is there a more elegant/readable way to do this scaling operation in C#:

```
ImageProcessing.Resize(original, 80, (int)((float)original.Height * (80f / original.Width)));
```

Where "original" is the .Net Image class and Image.Width and Image.Height are thus integers.

Comment: These questions are better asked over at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @RonBeyer One-liners are typically quite poor fits for [codereview.se].

Comment: I didn't know that there was such a thing.

Comment: In either case, here's what you ask yourself, 1) Does it work? 2) Can my coworker read it and understand it? 3) Could it be refactored easily? I'm guessing #3 is yes, by breaking out the variables individually, the compiler will optimize it away anyway so don't be afraid to use more code to make things cleaner, especially with simple calculations like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regular division followed by the floor operation (cast to `int`) is equivalent to integer division. Multiplication and division are left-associative. Therefore you can use this much shorter code:

```
ImageProcessing.Resize(original, 80, 80 * original.Height / original.Width);
```

To convince you, suppose `Width` and `Height` are `300` and `200`, respectively.  Then your code will do this:

```
(int)(200f * (80f / 300f)) = (int)(200f * 0.2666...) = (int)(53.3333...) = 53
```

And my code will do this (where `/` denotes integer division):

```
80 * 200 / 300 = 16000 / 300 = 53
```

Comment: Integer division in C# returns an int. For the scaling code to work, you need to do float division. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10851273/why-integer-division-in-c-sharp-returns-an-integer-but-not-a-float

Comment: Maybe I should have added that original is of type Image and thus .Width and .Height are ints.

Comment: @JohnShedletsky Take a closer look at what I proposed and try it out. The multiplication happens before the division, so the scaling will in fact work fine.

Comment: Oh I see. I can never remember the association direction or operator precedence rules.

Comment: Yours is better in a tight loop as well. Probably way faster (10x?) to avoid the floating point math and the typecast.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change code (which looks ok): Since "w/h" is [aspect ratio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect_ratio_%28image%29) separately computing it *may* produce more self-documenting code:

```
var aspectRatio = original.Width / (float)original.Height;
int newWidth = 80;
ImageProcessing.Resize(original, newWidth, (int)(newWidth / aspectRatio));
```