# C# datagridview: Defaultcellstyle is not working

Tags: c#, datagridview, cell-formatting

I have a problem about Datagridview cell formatting. I'm adding my example codes below,i tried many percentage formats about this but it is not working anymore. Where is the problem, can you help me?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        DataTable tb = new DataTable();
        DataRow row = tb.NewRow();
        tb.Rows.Add(row);
        tb.Columns.Add("Column1");
        tb.Rows[0][0] = "45";

        dataGridView1.DataSource = tb;
        dataGridView1.Columns[0].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "#.000\\%";
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by _not working_ exactly? You get error or exception? Unexpected result? If so, what result do you want?

Comment: i want to display this value 45%, but nothing happens, no error or exception, cell value is 45, not 45%

Answer (score 0):

Because both `"0"` and `"#"` specifiers are [custom **numeric** format strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Since your `"45"` is `string`, there will be no formatting *at all*.

As a solution, supply your first column values as a numeric like;

```
tb.Rows[0][0] = 45;
```

after that, divide your all first column values by `100.0` as a [floating point division](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10851273/447156) (you get `0.45` for example),

```
foreach (DataRow row in tb.Rows)
{
   row[0] = (int)row[0] / 100.0;
}
```

and use [The `"%"` Custom Specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#SpecifierPct) to format it like;

```
dataGridView1.Columns[0].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "#%";
```

This `%` specifier multiples your value by `100` and `%` symbol after it if your [`CurrentCulture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture) *already* has `%` as a [`PercentSymbol`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.percentsymbol).

For example;

```
Console.WriteLine((0.45).ToString("#%")); // prints 45%
```

Comment: Your solution is not working anymore, i have already same problem, is it about CurrentCulture issue?

Comment: @fth Can be. What do you mean by _not working_ exactly? Can you please be more specific?

Comment: It is the same problem, i control CurrentCulture, % specifier is exists.            So i can handle this problem using ToString("p0") for now

Comment: @fth What is `CurrentCulture` exactly?