# C# double datatype gives a 0 always

Tags: c#, operator-precedence

I have the following function that typically need to return a value. I calculate the value in a calculator app and I get values just fine. But in the program below the value variable value is always 0. I have tried using long, double, float but nothing works. Please help.

```
 public string CalculateElapsedPercent(DateTime endTime, DateTime startTime)
        {
            string result = string.Empty;
            DateTime currentTime = DateTime.Now;
            if (currentTime > endTime)
            {
                result = " (100 %)";
                return result;
            }
            long nr = (currentTime - startTime).Ticks;
            long dr = (endTime - startTime).Ticks;
            double value = (nr / dr) * 100.0;
            result = " (" + value.ToString() + " %)";
            return result;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since both `nr` and `dr` are `long`, the result of `(nr / dr)` is `long`, and since `dr` is greater that `nr`, the result is equal to `0`.

In order to fix that, you can convert it to `double` during calculation:

```
double value = ((double)nr / (double)dr) * 100.0;
```

Or you can define `nr` and `dr` as `double`s:

```
double nr = (currentTime - startTime).Ticks;
double dr = (endTime - startTime).Ticks;
double value = (nr / dr) * 100.0;
```

The behavior in your original code sample is called integer division. See [Division operator article in C# Specification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691373(v=vs.71).aspx) or [Why integer division in c# returns an integer but not a float?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10851273/why-integer-division-in-c-sharp-returns-an-integer-but-not-a-float) stackoverflow question for more info

Comment: So should nr be long and dr be double or any other type?

Comment: you can fix it with a couple casts, `((double)nr / (double)dr)`

Comment: Actually casting only one is enough, the compiler automatically uses the type with the most precision for the operation.

Answer (score 1):

`nr` and `dr` are integers, which means the `nr/dr` is an integer division, and since `dr` will always be larger than `nr`, you get zero.

Convert them to a `double` before dividing:

```
double nr = Convert.ToDouble((currentTime - startTime).Ticks);
double dr = Convert.ToDouble((endTime - startTime).Ticks);
double value = (nr / dr) * 100.0;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are performing integer division (`nr / dr`), which means you lose all the decimal values.

You instead want to perform floating point division.  You can do that by casting `nr` or `dr` to `double`.  Or, in your case, you could just move up the multiplication by `100.0` a little (multiplying by `100.0`, forces `nr` to be cast to a `double`, which then means that `dr` will also be automatically cast to `double` for the division):

```
double value = nr * 100.0 / dr;
```

Comment: This is what I would do, it's less verbose and equally effective.

Answer (score 0):

nr and dr are both `long` which is essentially integers. If you go with a (nr / dr) and `dr` is larger than `nr`, you would end up with zero as a result of the division. Just cast nr and dr to double and your problems would be solved. :)

```
    public string CalculateElapsedPercent(DateTime endTime, DateTime startTime)
    {
        string result = string.Empty;
        DateTime currentTime = DateTime.Now;
        if (currentTime > endTime)
        {
            result = " (100 %)";
            return result;
        }
        long nr = (currentTime - startTime).Ticks;
        long dr = (endTime - startTime).Ticks;
        double value = ((double)nr / (double)dr) * 100.0;
        result = " (" + value.ToString() + " %)";
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Others have already explained the issue, but I would also like to suggest a little improvement to your method. For example, like this:

```
public static string CalculateElapsedPercent(DateTime endTime, DateTime startTime)
{
    double ratio;
    DateTime currentTime = DateTime.Now;
    if (currentTime > endTime)
    {
        ratio = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        var elapsed = currentTime - startTime;
        var total = endTime - startTime;
        ratio = elapsed.TotalMinutes / total.TotalMinutes;
    }
    return string.Format(" ({0:P2})", ratio);
}
```