# Unity debug log full float

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I confused , this is my c sharp script that create and log the float:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class guicontrol : MonoBehaviour {
    void CalculatePosition(string ObjectName) {
        GameObject theobject = GameObject.Find (ObjectName);
        int selectedwidth = 1366;
        int selectedheight = 768;
        int screenwidth = Screen.width;
        int screenheight = Screen.height;
        float coordinatey = theobject.transform.localPosition.y;
        float coordinatex = theobject.transform.localPosition.x;
        float coordinatez = theobject.transform.localPosition.z;
        Debug.Log ("work at current stats : " + screenwidth + " " + screenheight);
        if (screenwidth != selectedwidth || screenheight != selectedheight) {

            float coordinateytomove = (screenheight / selectedheight) * coordinatey;
            float coordinatextomove = (screenwidth / selectedwidth) * coordinatex;
            Debug.Log (coordinateytomove + " " + coordinatextomove);

        }

    }
}
```

When I calculate it manually in calculator , the result of `coordinatextomove` was :

> -2.99853587116

but in the debug log was :

> -3 0

`-3` was the `coordinateytomove` which don't change from its current coordinate , but why if the `coordinatextomove` changed , its debug logged `0` instead of `-2.99853587116` ? If there's previous post answered this question , forgive me and give me the link of the post :) .

Comment: If you are trying to select objects in a area of the screen you may want to do `camera.WorldToScreenPoint(theobject.transform.position);` and get your `coordinatex` and `coordinatey`  from that. that will give you the x and y coordinates on the screen of the game object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`screenheight / selectedheight` will give you integer division ignoring anything to the right of the `.` after you get a result. You need to cast one of the two as a float before you divide

```
float coordinateytomove = ((float)screenheight / selectedheight) * coordinatey;
float coordinatextomove = ((float)screenwidth / selectedwidth) * coordinatex;
```

You could also just declare the variables as `float` and not need to do the cast later.

```
int selectedwidth = 1366;
int selectedheight = 768;
float screenwidth = Screen.width;
float screenheight = Screen.height;
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10851273/why-integer-division-in-c-sharp-returns-an-integer-but-not-a-float for more info.