# How to write a quadratic equation solver? (C#)

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a simple quadratic equation (x^2 + px + q = 0) solver but the answer I get is always wrong. My code looks like this

```
double p, q;

Console.Write("Insert the value of p: ");
int p = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

Console.Write("Insert the value of q: ");
int q = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

Console.WriteLine("x1 = " + (-p/2 + Math.Sqrt((p/2) ^ 2 - q )));
Console.WriteLine("x2 = " + (-p/2 - Math.Sqrt((p/2) ^ 2 - q)));
```

My guess is that there is something wrong with the `"x1 = " + (-p/2 + Math.Sqrt((p/2) ^ 2 - q )));` and the `x2 = + (-p/2 - Math.Sqrt((p/2) ^ 2 - q)));` parts.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's typical to see three coefficients: a*x^2 + b*x + c = 0.  Mind the special cases.

Comment: Give example input, incorrect result and expected result.

Comment: Note that integer division truncates after the decimal.

Comment: `p` is an `int` so unless it is even, `p/2` [isn't what you think it is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10851273/).

Comment: `^` is **xor**, change it into `Math.Power`

Comment: Another issue is possible *complex* value solution. You may want `Complex` type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My guess is that there is something wrong with the `x1 = ...` and the `x2 = ...` parts.

Here is what's wrong with them:

- Both `p` and `q` are `int`; they should be `double`, otherwise division by 2 would truncate the result.
- `n ^ 2` does not mean "squared" in C#. Use `Math.Power(x, 2)` instead
- You can keep `int.Parse` or change to `double.Parse` if you would like to allow fractional input for `p` and `q`.
- You never check that `p` is positive. This is required to ensure that the square root is defined.

Answer (score 0):

**ax^2 + bx + c = 0**

The formula for quadratics is:

```
(-b ± sqrt(b^2 - 4*a*c)) / 2a
```

So since your x^2 has no number in front, you can simplify to:

```
(-b ± sqrt(b^2 - 4*c)) / 2
```

So for you:

```
(-p/2 ± sqrt(p^2 - 4*q)) / 2
```