# c# percentage calculation explanation

Tags: c#, percentage

i have some understanding problems, with the percent calculation in c#

Why is this working.

```
100 * usedDiskSpace/maxDiskSpace
```

and this not...

```
((usedDiskSpace/maxDiskSpace)*100)
```

I didn't get it.

Why ?

for better explanation. I try to calculate the percentage of a harddisk volume. I programmed in other languages like Actionscript or php, or JAVA. I do not understand, why the result of the lower calculation will result a 0 value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does integer division in C# return an integer and not a float?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10851273/why-does-integer-division-in-c-sharp-return-an-integer-and-not-a-float)

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] (that we can copy and paste into a console app and run). The answer depends on the variable types involved.

Answer (score 5):

You have a differing order of operations.

Your first example, `100 * usedDiskSpace/maxDiskSpace`, is the same as `(100*usedDiskSpace)/maxDiskSpace`.

Your second example, `(usedDiskSpace/maxDiskSpace)*100` is doing the division before the multiplication. In integer division, anything after a whole number is truncated. Since (presumably) maxDiskSpace is always larger than usedDiskSpace, the result will be 0 * 100, or 0.

We can work through this with some toy numbers for the sake of an example.

```
int a = 10;
int b = 20;

Console.WriteLine(100*a/b); // Output: 50
// 100*10/20
// (100*10)/20
// 1000/20
// 50
Console.WriteLine((a/b)*100); // Output: 0
// (10/20)*100
// (0)*100 <- 0, rather than 0.5 due to how integer division works
// 0
```

Answer (score 3):

**Integer Division** and **Order of Operations**

When you divide the two *integers*, you get an integer result. Say you have values `40` and `50`. When all you have are integers, `40/50` is just `0`. There's no such thing as `.8` in integer land. Even if you also multiply by `100`, the division has already happened and `100*0` is still `0`.

But if you multiply the numerator by `100` *first*, you get `4000/50`. That still leaves room for an integer result: `80`.

That's what happened here. The first example executes the multiplication first. The second example executes the division first.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is likely caused by [integer division](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10851273/why-does-integer-division-in-c-sharp-return-an-integer-and-not-a-float).

The other answers are great if you are looking for a result that is a whole number (e.g. `10%`). If you are looking for a result with multiple decimal points (e.g. `10.57%`) then consider using:

```
var bob = ((usedDiskSpace * 1.0 / maxDiskSpace) * 100);
```

or even simpler:

```
var bob = usedDiskSpace * 100.0 / maxDiskSpace;
```

Multiplying by `1.0` (or `100.0`) will ensure that integer division is **not** used (since `1.0` and `100.0` are `double`.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you made integer division. Just cast as `float` or `double` to achieve desired result.

```
int usedDiskSpace = 230, maxDiskSpace = 980;

// integer division
int res = 100 * usedDiskSpace / maxDiskSpace;
// 23
res = ((usedDiskSpace / maxDiskSpace) * 100);
// 0

// floating point division
float resF =100f * usedDiskSpace / maxDiskSpace;
// 23.4693871
resF = (((float)usedDiskSpace / maxDiskSpace) * 100);
// 23.4693871
```

Answer (score 0):

In mathematical calculus, arrangement of parentheses are determinative. In the following expression:

> 100 * usedDiskSpace/maxDiskSpace

first **100** multiplied in **usedDiskSpace** then divided to **maxDiskSpace**. For example:

> 100 * 50 / 20 = 5000 / 20 = 250

But in the second one the calculation is as follows:

> ((usedDiskSpace/maxDiskSpace)*100)

first **usedDiskSpace** divided to **maxDiskSpace** then multiplied in **100**. The previous example in this scenario acts as follows:

> ((50 / 20) * 100) = 2 * 100 = 200

Please note that if **usedDiskSpace** and **maxDiskSpace** variables are an integer type, in that case, division result will be an integer one:

> 50 / 20 = 2 (not 2.5)

To obtain an equal result in your mentioned expressions, you should define **usedDiskSpace** and **maxDiskSpace** variables as float or double types.