# Value of complex algebraic expression remains zero

Tags: c, gcc

I have this code in C, and for some reason instead of properly working with numbers, it outputs zero all the time.
Can someone explain me what is going on here? I know C#, but not C.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    // I want to express 1/6n*(n + 1)(2n + 1)

    int n = 1;
    while(n != 0){
        scanf("%d", &n);
        printf("%d", 1/6 * n * (n + 1) * (2 * n + 1));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

I am using Code::Blocks + GCC compiler.

Comment: `1/6` is an integer division resulting in zero.

Comment: Modifying it to `printf("%d", 1.0/6.0 * n * (n + 1) * (2 * n + 1));` does not help either.

Comment: `%d` takes an `int`, not a `double`. You need to enable compiler warnings.

Comment: In that case the result will be `double`, but you use the format string for `int`

Comment: http://c-faq.com/expr/truncation1.html

Comment: Apparently it works the same way in C#: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10851273/why-does-integer-division-in-c-sharp-return-an-integer-and-not-a-float

Comment: @melpomene except that format specifiers are not needed there because `.ToString()` works fine.

Comment: Yes, but your question is why `1/6` is `0`.

Comment: Use `printf("%f", 1/6.0 * n * (n + 1) * (2 * n + 1));` - you need to make at least one of your division operands floating point, and you need to use `%f` to format the output as floating point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

    int n = 1;
    while(n != 0){
        scanf("%d", &n);
        printf("%d", n * (n + 1) * (2 * n + 1) / 6);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well. Not really. The *right* solution is `printf("%d", n * (n + 1) * (2 * n + 1) / 6);`

Comment: What is the difference?

Comment: Floating point is evil, so avoid it when possible.

Comment: Thank you for your help!