# How do I return a LinkedList collection from a lambda?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, linked-list

I have a `LinkedList<Point>` which I'm trying to apply a lambda to:

```
LinkedList<Point> node = LinkedPoints.Where<Point>(x => x.X + x.Y / someValue % 2 == 0);
```

..where `LinkedPoints` is a `LinkedList<Point>`. I want to create a new `LinkedList<Point>` from the original where the coordinates of the `Point` added together and divided by some value results in an even number. The actual condition of the lambda isn't important because currently the code above does not work, and I'd like to know why and how I can make it work.

I think that this lambda is operating on `Point` and so it'll return `List<Point>` however I want a new `LinkedList<Point>` - how can I achieve this?

Comment: `x.X + x.Y / someValue % 2` I strongly suggest adding `(` and `)` to make that calculation easier to read.

Comment: The actual condition I'm using is `x.X / nudDivisor.Value + x.Y / nudDivisor.Value % 2 == 0` - how would you split this up to be readable?

Answer (score 4):

Just use the [constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.linkedlist-1.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_Collections_Generic_LinkedList_1__ctor_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable__0__) of `LinkedList` that accepts an `IEnumerable` parameter:

```
LinkedList<Point> node =
    new LinkedList<Point>(LinkedPoints.Where(x => x.X + x.Y / someValue % 2 == 0));
```

---

You can also create an extension method similar to the `.ToList()` and `.ToArray()` methods:

```
static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static LinkedList<T> ToLinkedList<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection)
    {
        return new LinkedList<T>(collection);
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
LinkedList<Point> node = 
    LinkedPoints.Where(x => x.X + x.Y / someValue % 2 == 0).ToLinkedList();
```

---

### Notes:

- `.Where<Point>` can be simplified to just `.Where` because the type is inferred from the list.
- As [mjwills](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34092/mjwills) indicated in the comments, it's highly recommended to use parenthesis in your condition to make the calculation logic clearer and to avoid mistakes. See [Arithmetic operators precedence and associativity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/arithmetic-operators#operator-precedence-and-associativity) for reference. Also, beware not to fall victim for unintended [Integer Division](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10851273/8967612).