# Explain this type of cast?

Tags: c#, casting

I am learning casting and conversion techniques and I thought I had the hang of it until i came across this. 
I know it is a way to divide a int by a decimal but can someone break it down how it works in simple terms? Cant seem to get my head around this type of cast. Thank you

```
int value1 = 12;
decimal value2 = 6.2m;
float value3 = 4.3f;

int result1 = (int)((decimal) value1 / value2);
```

Output:

```
Result1 = 1
```

Comment: What is `value1`?

Comment: The decimal cast is redundant since `value2` is a decimal already

Comment: It casts `value1` to `decimal` and the result of `value1 / value2` to `int`. Can you elaborate where exactly you are stuck?

Comment: @BiesiGrr but `value1` isn't.

Comment: If both `value1` and `value2` were of type `int`, the `(decimal)` cast would be needed because otherwise, it would cause an [integer division](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10851273/8967612). Whoever wrote that code probably was just too careful trying to avoid integer division so they used an unnecessary cast. The `(int)` cast, on the other hand, is just to cast the end result to an `int`.

Comment: I think your question is about the int cast? `value1 / value2` results in `1.93...` The int cast now truncates the decimal, so `1` is left . @CodeCaster it specifically does not round, it truncates.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay: value1 will automatically be cast to decimal due to value2 being decimal -  so the explicit cast to decimal is redundant

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay `(int / decimal)` type is `decimal`

Comment: It's a [numeric cast](https://www.dotnetperls.com/numeric-casts)

Comment: What is your actual problem here?  Is it the decimal cast or the int cast, or the combination of both?

Comment: @ARCHER It was the decimal cast that was confusing me, this solution to a challenge was provided by microsoft, was confused as to why they would of done it this way and wanted clarifaction

Comment: @Jaybizl Okay - thanks for clarifying.  Just wanted to make sure you got an answer to your actual problem :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's start with something important. Casting `value1` to `decimal` is obsolete, you get the same exact result from:

```
int result1 = (int)(value1 / value2);
```

You can see the result of *not* casting to `int` by doing this:

```
var result1 = (value1 / value2);
Console.WriteLine(result1.GetType());
```

> Result: System.Decimal

If you try to assign that directly to `int` you get

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'decimal' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

So you need to *explicitly* cast the `decimal` to `int` to assign it to `result1`

Comment: The reason you get the same even without the decimal cast is that the compiler automatically does it for you. See [here](https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgTAjAWAFBQMwAJboMLoN7LpGYZQAs6AsgBQCU+hxTAlgHYAu6AbgIYA2AVwCmcdAF50cGAG5GTIsCEBjZgFt+3fsJjj0ANgB0MVbKTzibTgCchAZwF9OE6pdrVegkegD0mzzFpTcyIoOABOaht7R0C5dABfZHigA===)

Comment: @BiesiGrr `compiler automatically does it for you`, yeah, but IMHO we should be handling this.

Comment: This was a solution provided by Microsoft to a challenge IMO I thought there is no need to use the decimal cast but just wanted clarification.