# Not getting correct volume of sphere

Tags: c#, math, formula, volume

this is my code

```
double inputrad = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
double circlevolume = 4/3 * Math.Pow(circlerad, 3) * Math.PI;
```

The volume of a circle with radius 2.5 is 65, but i am getting 49. Why?

Comment: use something like `4/3.0` otherwise you get integer division `4/3` which will give `1`

Comment: `double circlevolume = 4 * Math.PI / 3 * Math.Pow(circlerad, 3);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to write something like `4/3.0` or `4.0/3` or `4/3d` etc.. otherwise you are using *integer division* `4/3` which will give exactly `1`.

You can also, as suggested by Dmitry Bychenko, change the order of operations to get a floating point result before applying division:

`4 * Math.PI / 3 * Math.Pow(circlerad, 3)`.

The point is, *integer divided by integer* is integer division, and you absolutely need to avoid this.

For further information, you can see this Q&A here: [Why does integer division in C# return an integer and not a float?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10851273/why-does-integer-division-in-c-sharp-return-an-integer-and-not-a-float)