# Float Evaluation returns integer?

Tags: c#, .net, math

I recently started with the euler Project for practice, I completed 1 and 2, but 3 is just not working. I used the same line of code for every solution to check if the number is decimal or not. This worked fine except this time, but I dont know why. This code

```
            for (float i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            {
                float temp = i / 3;
                float temp2 = i/ 5;
                if ((temp % 1) == 0 || (temp2 % 1) == 0)
                {
                    num += i;
                }
            }
```

worked perfectly fine, but this one (which is basically the same)

```
float input = 600851475143;
for (float i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            float temp = input/i;
            if ((temp % 1) == 0)
            {
                Console.Write(temp + ", ");
            }
```

just returns every number. Then I tried this

```
float temp = 10/9;
Console.WriteLine(temp);
```

But it just returns 1. So i thought of an overflow or something like that, but my next approach didnt work either:

```
float temp = 10/9;
bool temp2 = (temp%1) == 0;
Console.WriteLine(temp2);

Return: True
```

I dont now what to do anymore, does someone know why this happens? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `10.0/9` or `10/9.0` or whatever that makes the expression be evaluated as float rather than an int that is assigned to a float variable.

Comment: Thank you first of all. But I tried it and it didnt change the result  ` float input = 600851475143f;
        for (float i = 0f; i < 1000.0; i++)
        {
            float temp = input/i;
            if ((temp % 1) == 0)
            {
                Console.Write(i + ", ");
            }
            
        } `

Comment: Use Double not Float so such a high amount

Comment: actually use 64 bit longs and check input % i directly, don't divide first then check modulus 1

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10851273/why-does-integer-division-in-c-sharp-return-an-integer-and-not-a-float

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`float` in C# has precision of 6-9 digits according to [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/floating-point-numeric-types), `600851475143` divided by maximum `i` in the loop (i.e. 999) will have more than 9 digits in mantissa so `float` will not be able to cover fractional part, so try switching to `double` or even `decimal`:

```
double input = 600851475143;
for (double i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    double temp = input / i;
    if ((temp % 1) == 0)
    {
        Console.Write(temp + ", ");
    }
}
```

Also I would say that you can use `long`'s in this case:

```
long input = 600851475143;
for (long i = 1; i < 1000; i++)
{
    var x = (input % i);
    if (x == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(input / i);
    }
}
```

As for the last snippet - `10` and `9` in `10/9` are `int`'s, so the result of `10/9` is an `int` and equals to `1`, which give you the result you get.