# How to aggregate data, pass and fail as final result?

Tags: c#

I have a list of result either having or not having `Data` plus has `Pass` and `Fail` like below,

```
var results = new List<Result>
{
    new Result{Data = new Data{Name = "A"}, Pass = 1, Fail = 0},
    new Result{Data = new Data{Name = "B"}, Pass = 3, Fail = 1},
    new Result{Pass = 1, Fail = 0}
};
```

I need to aggregate data and need this as final result output,

```
var finalResult = new FinalResult
{
    Datas = new List<Data> { new Data { Name = "A" }, new Data { Name = "B" } },
    TotalPass = 5,
    TotalFail = 1,
    Divident = 5/1
}
```

I tried something like below, but `totalPass` and `totalfail`, are not coming correct. Plus, how to aggregate `Data`?

```
int totalPass = 0;
int totalfail = 0;

var finalResult = new FinalResult();

foreach (var r in results)
{
    totalPass += r.Pass;
    totalfail += r.Fail;
}

finalResult.TotalFail = totalPass;
finalResult.TotalFail = totalfail;
finalResult.Divident = totalPass / totalfail;
```

Here are the two classes:

```
public class FinalResult
{
    public List<Data> Datas { get; set; }
    public int TotalPass { get; set; }
    public int TotalFail { get; set; }
    public int Divident { get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
    public Data Data { get; set; }
    public int Pass { get; set; }
    public int Fail { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: `Divident` should not be an integer, use `decimal` or `double` instead. To get a list, it's easiest to use LINQ and project (map) each `Result` into its `Data` property: `finalResult.Datas = results.Select(r => r.Data).ToList()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this easily using LINQ:

```
var finalResult = new FinalResult
{
    Datas = results.Where(r => r.Data != null).Select(r => r.Data).ToList(),
    TotalPass = results.Sum(r => r.Pass),
    TotalFail = results.Sum(r => r.Fail)
};

// Beware of division by zero and integer division.
finalResult.Divident = finalResult.TotalPass / finalResult.TotalFail;
```

Notes:

- You should probably check the value of `TotalFail` before the division to prevent division by zero.
- As [Groo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/69809/groo) mentioned in the comments, `Divident` should probably be declared as `double` and you should cast one of the parts to `double` unless you do want [Integer Division](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10851273/8967612).

Comment: Thanks. null `Data` also coming. I wan not to select it

Comment: @user584018 Updated.