# How to get the int value last digit of the year?

Tags: c#

Here's the code:

```
            string year = Convert.ToString(formModel.JamKeluar.Year);
            int aas = year.IndexOf((char)1);
```

How can I get the last 3 digit of the year as int? example if the year 2021, I need 21 as int

Comment: If you want an integer then you can only get 21 not 021.

Comment: its ok, can u give me example code

Comment: What if the year was 206? What output is expected?

Comment: What if the year is 10134? What output is expected?

Comment: @mjwills ouch, are you telling me that we are facing another Y2K bug? :-)

Comment: @Steve Maybe. Honestly - it really depends what the OP wants, which is _super_ unclear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is the [Remainder operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/arithmetic-operators#remainder-operator-) in C#

> The remainder operator % computes the remainder after dividing its
> left-hand operand by its right-hand operand.

```
int year = formModel.JamKeluar.Year;
int aas = year % 1000;
Console.WriteLine(aas);
```

Comment: If you take the remainder of the [integer division](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10851273/why-does-integer-division-in-c-sharp-return-an-integer-and-not-a-float) between 2021 and 1000 the result is 21. The same concept applies to any other combination. For example if the remainder between an integer an 2 is 1 then you have an odd number, instead if it is 0 then you have an even number (3 % 2 = 1, 4 % 2 = 0) More info in the link above

Answer (score 0):

You can take last 3 digits like this

```
  string year = Convert.ToString(formModel.JamKeluar.Year);
  int aas = Convert.ToInt16(year.Substring(1));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
string year = DateTime.Now.Year.ToString();
int n = year.Length;
int treamedYear = int.Parse(string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", year[n - 3], year[n - 2], year[n - 1]));
Console.WriteLine(inttreamedYear);
```

If you convert it to `int` data type, the 0 at the starting position will be removed automatically. If you need that 0, use string.
`string treamedYear = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", year[n - 3], year[n - 2], year[n - 1]);`