# Wrong calculation c#

Tags: c#, calculation

I have some code that divides the number of elements in a collection by one hundred. But in the end it shows the wrong value.

```
private void FillPages()
        {
            double numofpages = listcoinslist.Count / 100;
            MessageBox.Show(listcoinslist.Count + " " + numofpages);
        }
```

[The picture of the calculation result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H33D8.png)

I should get 65.6, instead I get 65.
The same number is displayed on the label. This is not a display error, but a strange calculus error.

Comment: `.Count` is an `int`, `100` is an `int`. `int / int` is an `int`. Assigning an `int` to a `double` does not change that.

Comment: Use `/ 100.0` and try again

Comment: Might be a better duplicate, but related: [Why does integer division in C# return an integer and not a float?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10851273/1441)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to rounding to int values because both values seem to be ints. Make sure you have at least one decimal number.

Make sure you devide with a float or double by adding `.0`, for example:

`double numofpages = listcoinslist.Count / 100.0;`

Answer (score 0):

```
double numofpages = (double)listcoinslist.Count / 100;
```

The problem was that you need to specify the number of elements in the collection as double.