# constructor properties

Tags: c#, class, constructor

I want to calculate the HRA, DA etc. I have to define a constructor, But the error pops up mentioning that The variable `basic_salary' is assigned but its value is never used.

code:

```
public void read()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the employee name");
    empname = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the basic salary of an employee");
    int basic_salary = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
    calculate();
}

class program
{
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Employee employeobj = new Employee();
    employeobj.read();
    employeobj.display();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `read()` function you are defining `basic_salary` variable **again**, instead of using `basic_salary` defined at the class level.

To solve your issue, try

```
public void read()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the employee name");
    empname = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the basic salary of an employee");
    //insted of defining new integer as basic_salary, use existing class level basic_salary variable
    basic_salary = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); 
    calculate();
}
```

Comment: but still when I input basic salary as 1000 the hra is coming 0, please help me with that as well

Comment: You are getting `0` as a result because of type of `HRA`. Change type of `HRA, DA, GS, incometax, netsalary` to double or decimal. Helpfult like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10851273/why-does-integer-division-in-c-sharp-return-an-integer-and-not-a-float

Comment: okay I edited the above code, is it correct ?

Comment: okay it worked after reading the above post by changing 100 to 100.0 & others as well thanks alot