# Why is this variable being assigned 0 even after dividing and being initialized?

Tags: c#, for-loop

Here is my code below-

```
double divBuy = 0;
for (int j = 0; j < equityCheckArray.Count; j++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < noOfBuyIndicators; i++)
            {
                buySum += buySignal[i][j];
            }
            divBuy = buySum / noOfBuyIndicators;
            averageBuy[j] = divBuy;
        }
```

`buySum` and `noOfIndicators` both have values assigned to them as 1 and 3 respectively. As you can see, `divBuy` is also initialized correctly and is not a null value. Still, after `divBuy = buySum / noOfIndicators` line is passed, 1/3 is not assigned to `divBuy` and the value remains as 0. Why is this happening?

Apologies if this question has been asked multiple times in the past. Thanks in advance

Comment: What are the types of the variables being used?  Is the `for` loop being entered at all?  Can you provide a [mcve] which fully demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Are `buySum` and `noOfBuyIndicators` both `int` by any chance? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10851273/why-does-integer-division-in-c-sharp-return-an-integer-and-not-a-float

Answer (score 1):

> `double divBuy = buySum / noOfBuyIndicators;`

When `buySum`  and `noOfBuyIndicators` are both integers then the division will be an integer division.

Meaning: `1 / 3 == 0`.

The fix is simple:

```
  divBuy = (double)buySum / noOfBuyIndicators;
```

Comment: `divBuy` should likely be `decimal` too, given what looks like a financial context.

Comment: Yes, but that is a separate problem. double will do for a lot of finance stuff.