# How do I calculate correct in C# Console App?

Tags: c#, console

I'm trying to calculate the following equation in a C# console application:

```
double equation = 25 + -2 * 3 / 14; 
Console.WriteLine(equation);
```

And the outcome is 25.

Which is not the accurate answer to the equation. Does anyone mind explaining to me what I have to do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does integer division in C# return an integer and not a float?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10851273/why-does-integer-division-in-c-sharp-return-an-integer-and-not-a-float)

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        double equation = 25 + -2 * 3 / 14d;
        Console.WriteLine(equation);
    }
}
```

The issue is that you are doing your operations with integers (whole numbers) so the result will be an integer that you cast as a double.  What you need to do is specify that you division operation is done on a float or double so the answer to the division part will not be a whole number.  You can also do this with `14.0` or `14f` but it is better to stick to the same data type to avoid conversion issues later on.

You can test your code here:  https://dotnetfiddle.net/Tlws6e

Answer (score 2):

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        double equation = 25 + -2 * 3 / 14.0;
        Console.WriteLine(equation);
    }
}
```

This should help. When you want results in doubles and floats, and you are using literals, add a `.0`. This results in `24.5714285714286`.

Answer (score 1):

For more precision you can use decimal type

```cs
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        decimal equation = 25m + -2m * 3m / 14m;
        Console.WriteLine(equation);
    }
}
```

Demo:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/QI2UaQ

Exact result:
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=25+%2B+-2+*+3+%2F+14