# Find nearest down value of target in multiply with

Tags: c#

I am trying to find out the nearest down value of my Target value, for example:

The target value  is 9
and my multiply number is 2
so I want the nearest down value of 9 which is in the table of 2, that is 8

I tried the mode method but did not get the result.

Comment: Assuming I've understood your question correctly, calculate all factors to the first factor that is greater than your target value; i.e. if target is 9 then 2,4,6,8,10. The penultimate value is your answer.

Comment: Just want to understand the question clearly, are you looking for the down value of the target just in the multiplier number?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you problem correctly, you want the nearest lower number that can be divided by the number. This simple function should help you:

```cs
int NearestDown(int n, int d)
{
    return (n/d)*d;
}
```

Given a number and the divisor, it will return "NearestDown". It's using integer division to find the number of times the number can be divided and then multiplies it with the divisor.
You could also just subtract the modulo, like this:

```cs
int NearestDown(int n, int d)
{
    return n-(n % d);
}
```

Here a link about integer division:
[Why does integer division in C# return an integer and not a float?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10851273/why-does-integer-division-in-c-sharp-return-an-integer-and-not-a-float)

Comment: @jarmanso7: There, fixed it.