# changing celsius to fahrenheit and vice versa in c#

Tags: c#, .net, console-application

please help me out! The Fahrenheit one is working ok but the celsius one is not working the output is always negative for some reason. I'm a beginner so please be beginner-friendly, I'm going by what my high school teacher has taught me and it has to include else if statements as that is our lesson.

```
double c= 0;
double f=0;
System.Console.Write(" would you like to convert from Celcius or Fahrenheit: ");
string x = Console.ReadLine();
x= x.ToUpper();

if (x == "Fahrenheit");
{
    System.Console.Write(" please enter degrees: ");
    f= Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
    double  ferTocel = (f - 32) * 5 / 9; 
    System.Console.WriteLine(" Your new value in Degrees Celcius is: " + 
    ferTocel + " degrees celsius"); 
}
else (x == "Celsius");
{
    System.Console.Write(" please enter a celsius: ");
    c = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
    double  celTofer =  (9/5)* c + 32;

    System.Console.WriteLine(" Your new value in Degrees Fahrenheit is: " + celTofer + " degrees Fahrenheit");
}
```

Comment: Duplicate of: [Division returns zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9288904/division-returns-zero), [C# is rounding down divisions by itself](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6311855/8967612)

Comment: Can you give a concrete input and output example? Note that `9/5` does an "integer division", i.e. ist is equal to 1. You propbably want `9.0/5.0`. Also: this is not related to "ASP.NET".

Comment: and x= x.ToUpper(); makes your Conditional statemenst fail

Comment: `else (x == "Celsius");` should be `else if (x == "Celsius")`: missing "if" to be added, additional ";" to be removed

Comment: `if (x == "Fahrenheit");` - also here an additional ";" which has to be removed.