# how to enforce the evaluation type of an expression to be double

Tags: c#, winforms, floating-point, precision, flee

how could I make sure that the expression is always evaluated as a double even if it has no double in it, I came across this website https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/floating-point-numeric-types, It says :

[image: check the relevant part from here]
so how can I override this problem and make sure that the expression is always evaluated as a double,

I am trying to use the library of Flee, and whenever I put a fraction in it like(4/3) it deals with it as an integer, not even a float, this ruins the whole calculation so I have to get around this problem,

If I try and use the following expression it works

(4.0/3) or (4/3.0) = 1.33333
the faulty case is as follows
(4/3) = 1
hopefully my explanation is clear

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# is rounding down divisions by itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6311855/c-sharp-is-rounding-down-divisions-by-itself)

Comment: @Charlieface unfortunately it does not, this works well, but when I use it with Flee library it crashes because I am trying to allow the user to enter mathematical expressions containing variables, Flee´s parser considers the d as a variable and crashes, I was thinking of a solution that would make all the mathematical evaluations done in double, like canceling the integer division completely.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the docs, that is a feature of the language. You can always cast either the numerator or the denominator into a float or double which will end with a result of the same type:

```
int a = 4;
int b = 3;
double result = (double)a / b;
```

Comment: this works well, but when I use it with Flee library it crashes because I am trying to allow the user to enter mathematical expressions containing variables, Flee´s parser considers the d as a variable and crashes, I was thinking of a solution that would make all the mathematical evaluations done in double, like canceling the integer division completely.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve the problem by forcing Flee Library to not consider any given input as Integer anymore, I did that by writing the following code:

```
ExpressionContext context = new ExpressionContext();
context.Options.IntegersAsDoubles = true;
```

Best of luck to you all

Answer (score 0):

## Solution 1

Use the double annotation which tells to the compiler that the number is actually a double

```cs
4d / 3
```

(d for double, also works for float using f)

## Solution 2

Use explicit casting

```cs
(double)4 / 3
```

Comment: this works well, but when I use it with Flee library it crashes because I am trying to allow the user to enter mathematical expressions containing variables, Flee´s parser considers the d as a variable and crashes, I was thinking of a solution that would make all the mathematical evaluations done in double, like canceling the integer division completely.