# Foreach way to iterate through years given months?

Tags: c#, foreach, iteration

```
var months = 36;
```

To iterate through the years and have access to each year number (according to how many months I have (above)), I'm currently doing:

```
var years = Convert.ToInt32(months / 12);

for (int i = 1; i <= years; i++)
{
    var year = 12 * i;
}
```

However, I'm sure there must be a way of populating a new list of integers as part of a `foreach` and looping through them (giving me access to the current element rather than recalculating it again inside the `for` loop). I'm looking for help writing that `foreach`. Possibly a LINQ  `.Select()`? I really don't like this current approach.

**Desired Result**

```
foreach(var year in new List<int>(){ 1, 2, 3})
{
}
```

Comment: A downvote's great if it's accompanied with an explanation. Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: slightly off topic, but you can do `var years = months / 12`, there is no need to `Convert.Int32`, both of your operands `months` and `12` are integer values and would produce an `int` output.

Comment: @Habib - thanks again. Rather basic question, but what if it were `4 / 3`?

Comment: it would be `1`, since the division is done for int values the result would be integer. similarly for `3 / 4`, the result would be `0`

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1205490/why-do-these-division-equations-result-in-zero

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this?:

```
foreach (var year in Enumerable.Range(1, months / 12))
```

Comment: Exactly like that, yes. Brilliant. Thanks mate.

Comment: +1, if Month value is `37` and the OP needs 4 years for it then `Enumerable.Range(1, (int) Math.Ceiling(month / 12d))`

Comment: @Habib - thanks. Valid point. I'm safe from that for now, but it's worth me including it just to be more defensive.

Comment: @Habib: True, there are a number of logical considerations to be made in this calculation.  Depending on what behavior the OP is looking for.