# Dividing one smaller number with the bigger one doesn't work without special decleration c#

Tags: c#, floating-point, declaration

This:

`float a = 2 / 4;
return a;`

Will output as 0, while this:

`float a = 2;
float b = 4;
float c = a / b;
return c;`

Will give a correct output 0.5.

Why am I getting this result?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1205490/why-do-these-division-equations-result-in-zero) answer your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C# interprets 2 and 4 as plain integers, 2/4 is 0 using integer math (floor of 0.5).

Try using `2f` and `4f` instead to have floating point numbers. Refer to this documentation to see all possible number literals https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/floating-point-numeric-types#real-literals.

Code below works as expected:

```cs
public static void Main()
{
    float a = 2f / 4f;
    Console.WriteLine(a);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because 2 and 4 are the type of integer.

```
Type type1 = 2.GetType();
Type type2 = 4.GetType();
```